# Как вернуть значение основной формы Enabled = true, когда закрываешь дочерную?

Tags: c#, winforms

**Form1**

```
...
       private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton8.Checked)
            {
                Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
                frm2.ShowDialog();
                frm2.MdiParent = this;
                this.Enabled = false;
            }
        } 
...
```

**Form2**

```
namespace ПАК_ИП_ОЭБ
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Я прочитал, что  надо где-то хранить ссылку на форму для которой вы установили Enabled = false, но не понял как передать эту ссылку во вторую форму так :

**Form1**

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);
frm2.ShowDialog();
```

**Form2**

```
 public Form2(Form1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Выдаёт ошибку требуется идентификатор

Comment: вы указали тип параметра, но не указали сам параметр ```Form2(Form1 myForm)```

Comment: tym32167 - Спасибо ошибки нет, но как теперь использовать эту ссылку в button2_Click. frm1.Enebled = true; - ошибка: "не существует в текущем контексте" ?

Comment: добавил ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
class MyForm2 : Form
{
    MyForm1 _form1;

    public MyForm2(MyForm1 form1)
    {
        _form1 = form1;
    }


    /// ......

    void Button_Click (object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        _form1.Enabled = true;      
    }
}
```